# What does "two or more data types in declaration specifiers " error means??

Tags: c, compiler-errors, declaration, format-specifiers

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int nt;
void main () {
  long int k;
}
```

When I run the above code in gcc, it didn't show any error. But when I run the below code, it threw an error message "two or more data types in declaration specifiers ".

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int nt;
void main () {
  long nt k;
}
```

Could anyone explain me what is this error all about??

Comment: You should avoid leaving typing mistakes in code snippets you share here. (I edited your `typdef` to `typedef`). Also, although gcc doesn't complain about it with the default compile options, `main()` should return `int`, not `void`. I recommend always using `-Wall -pedantic` flags.

Answer (score 3):

`typedef`s create *complete* types.

You cannot compose a type out of `long` and a typedef.

Comment: Nor can you 'add' `unsigned`, etc.  Qualifiers such as `const` or `volatile` can be added, though (with some caution required if there is a `const` pointer in the `typedef` itself).